# Fibocom L850-GL/Intel XMM 7360 driver does not work Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, drivers, lte

I have a Thinkpad T590 that I dual-boot Windows and Linux on. I installed an OEM Fibocom L850-GL WWAN card in the laptop, and after driver installation it works perfectly in Windows. However, after trying to set it up in my Fedora 37 Workstation installation I discovered that there was no official driver, and the card was only officially supported in USB mode.

I tried to install the unofficial PCIe driver found [here,](https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci) but was presented with the following error message, even after reboots:

```
  File "/home/quowlord/Downloads/xmm7360-pci-master/scripts/../rpc/open_xdatachannel.py", line 42, in <module>
    r = rpc.XMMRPC()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/quowlord/Downloads/xmm7360-pci-master/rpc/rpc.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.fp = os.open(path, os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/xmm0/rpc'
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
```

the output of `ls /dev` is:

```
autofs            cuse             full       kvm           media0  nvme0n1p1  ptmx           shm       tty0   tty17  tty25  tty33  tty41  tty5   tty58  tty9    ttyS16  ttyS24  ttyS4    urandom      vcs1   vcsa3  vcsu5        watchdog
block             disk             fuse       log           mei0    nvme0n1p2  ptp0           snapshot  tty1   tty18  tty26  tty34  tty42  tty50  tty59  ttyS0   ttyS17  ttyS25  ttyS5    usbmon0      vcs2   vcsa4  vcsu6        watchdog0
btrfs-control     dma_heap         gpiochip0  loop-control  mem     nvme0n1p3  pts            snd       tty10  tty19  tty27  tty35  tty43  tty51  tty6   ttyS1   ttyS18  ttyS26  ttyS6    usbmon1      vcs3   vcsa5  vfio         wwan0at0
bus               dri              hpet       lp0           mqueue  nvme0n1p4  random         stderr    tty11  tty2   tty28  tty36  tty44  tty52  tty60  ttyS10  ttyS19  ttyS27  ttyS7    usbmon2      vcs4   vcsa6  vga_arbiter  wwan0at1
char              drm_dp_aux0      hugepages  lp1           net     nvme0n1p5  rfkill         stdin     tty12  tty20  tty29  tty37  tty45  tty53  tty61  ttyS11  ttyS2   ttyS28  ttyS8    usbmon3      vcs5   vcsu   vhci         zero
console           drm_dp_aux1      hwrng      lp2           ng0n1   nvme0n1p6  rtc            stdout    tty13  tty21  tty3   tty38  tty46  tty54  tty62  ttyS12  ttyS20  ttyS29  ttyS9    usbmon4      vcs6   vcsu1  vhost-net    zram0
core              drm_dp_aux2      initctl    lp3           null    nvram      rtc0           tpm0      tty14  tty22  tty30  tty39  tty47  tty55  tty63  ttyS13  ttyS21  ttyS3   udmabuf  userfaultfd  vcsa   vcsu2  vhost-vsock
cpu               fb0              input      mapper        nvme0   port       sgx_provision  tpmrm0    tty15  tty23  tty31  tty4   tty48  tty56  tty7   ttyS14  ttyS22  ttyS30  uhid     v4l          vcsa1  vcsu3  video0
```

with no apparent device of the name mentioned in the error. Since the card works on Windows, it can be assumed it's installed correctly on a hardware level. Do you know where the device is/why it's not showing up in `/dev`?

Comment: The PCI driver seem to be [working](https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/blob/master/DEVICES.md).

Comment: @not2qubit The t590 or t490 (The laptops I'm troubleshooting) aren't listed on that page. Are you trying to indicate that my device therefore shouldn't be expected to work, or am I misreading your comment?

Comment: I'm saying that the list of tested devices are over 2 years old. So you should try to make it work with yours since some of the models seem very similar to those you have.  It would be interesting to see what your `lspci` and `lsusb` and possibly a screenshot of Windows *Device Manager*, would look like. It may be so simple that you're missing (or have some misconfigured) `init.rc` (not exclusive) scripts...

Comment: The `t490` work for [this guy](https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci/issues/177).

Comment: Okay. I would believe it's a misconfigured script. Let me get you the lspci, lsusb, and device manager screenshots.

Comment: You may want to edit your question, because it is not clear at all what you're actually trying to do, and the actual questionPlease also provide the commands you're using and not only the output. Maybe you will have more luck asking/filing an issue in that github repo. I see 2 modem  AT devices in your /dev, `wwan0at0` and `wwan0at1`...

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck, because there is no working Linux driver for the Fibocom L850-GL. You can read more about it [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Linux-support-for-WWAN-LTE-L850-GL-on-T580-T480/td-p/4067969) and [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/X1C-gen-6-Fibocom-L850-GL-Ubuntu-18-04/m-p/4078413).

Comment: I was unclear with my question. While your response was, indeed, the answer to the preface, my specific question was why the device that was polled (```xmm0```) does not show up in ```/dev```, and whether the WWAN card was getting 'mounted' by the system at all. ```LSPCI``` does show it, but it doesn't appear to be in ```/dev```